# Running a script onto springboard on iOS device

Tags: ios, ui-automation, springboard

I trying to find a way or a solution particularly to run a simple script on springboard but unable to find a way to do so. There's a instrument command but it does require a app name and run's the app where else I am interested in playing with springboard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I have seen claim to be able to do this is ExperiTest's SeeTestAutomation (http://experitest.com/automation/).

Unfortunately it is proprietary and expensive ($3500 per year for a single user license). I would love to hear some first hand accounts about how well it actually works, it does have a fairly impressive client list.

Hrmm... apparently eggplant iOS gateway may also be able to do this. Though there is a stated limitation that it cannot automate system popups: http://docs.testplant.com/?q=book/export/html/464

Comment: thanks buddy ! I was looking ways which not include any tool like using terminal via command lines. Still appreciated with your finding :)